# How to assign context and refresh it in Entity Framework?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I created a new entity object and bound it to controls in another window (edit window). After modifying and saving I assigned a new entity object into the one in the main window. The old entity object is bound into a datagrid, now I want the datagrid to display the data that I had modified and saved.

[ObjectContext.Refresh Method (RefreshMode, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx) seems to be what I want but I don't know how to use it correctly.

**In short :**
I have a main window with datagrid displaying the whole data of the table. Users can pick one row and edit it in a edit window. After saving, the datagrid should display what has been modified.

Comment: How have you structured your WPF - as vanilla/default project or MVVM?

Comment: ChrisBD, I drag and drop a entity to generate a datagrid in mainwindow. For edit window, I set a datacontext with a query. For example : datacontext = MyContext.customer.where(q=>q.id.equal(id_selected_from_mainwindow));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here is to use an `ObservableCollection` as your data source for the datagrid instead of the query.

And look at implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `Customer` class.

The `ObservableCollection` is initially populated by the database query. User changes are made to elements within the `ObservableCollection` and once complete you then just need to trigger transferring the changes to wherever you originally obtained your list of `Customer` objects

By doing this changes made both to the collection of Customers and to individual Customer objects (if present within the datagrid) will be automatically updated for you.

**edit**

I must admit that I'm a bit rushed to offer up any code at the moment, but [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252944.aspx) a pretty good article that explains how to use `ObservableCollections` and classes that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It also has code examples, which although in VB.NET should give you enough of an idea to get started.

In effect you separate your code into distinct layers UI (View), business logic (View Model) and data layer (Model where your entity framework resides).

You bnd your datagrid to the ObservableCollection type property in your Customers class and your edit csutomer window is bound to as instance of your Customer class.

Comment: ChrisBD, would you please show me a sample for how to make the collection of Customers update changes from an individual Customer objects ?

Comment: Hi - not enough time today to write and post code, but have a look at the article that I've added a link to in my answer - it'll explain more.

Comment: Even with the linked example, I am struggling to grasp how to use an ObservableCollection to detect changes made to an entity object from a separate window in an MVVM pattern. How can the ObservableCollection know one of its items is changed without having the View projects communicate with the Model project for entity object type and details?

Comment: Sorry Jesslyn, I haven't been on for a while. Bind your View XAML to the Observable collection. Any changes made to the collection are notified to the View by the NET framework. You don't have to do any handling yourself. For passing changes made by the user on the UI back to the database I'd suggest implementing a "Save" button that triggers a command to pass the updates back to the datalayer.